# d3.csv .slice data loading issue incomplete return of rows

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, slice

I have a csv.file with 15000 rows. This simplified function shows how the csv is read and how the display function is set up.
I .slice(start,stop) the data before I display them.

```
jQuery(function($) {

   display = function(data) {

      // console.log("start_b:" + start);
      // console.log("stop_b:" + stop);

  return plotData("#vis", data.slice(start,stop), plot);
  };

  url = keyfile;
  return d3.csv(url, display);
  });
```

My console.log shows the desired data, example: start=80, stop=160. However, my chart does not display consistently 80 rows. If I set 0,80 - it does display 80 rows; if I chose higher values, exapmple: 80,160 - it displays consistently 72 rows only. The data are displayed in a force layout.
Is there a good reason for this behavior ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Hard to tell without a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I thought that I had read a comment by Mike Bostock that the loading into a force layout form a csv was not consistent, but I cannot find that comment anymore and am not sure about the exact wording. If it is not something known then it has to be  in my code somewhere and I will go search for it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The fact that 8 items out of 80 are missing tells me that on every ten one is omitted - why I do not know yet.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the data matching in the force layout rather than the data loading. There's certainly no restriction in D3 itself in that regard and I would be very surprised if Mike had made a comment suggesting this.

Comment: Ok, the chart does not display 'duplicates' where column 1 has the same value - not sure that this makes sense to me

Comment: What does the data look like when it arrives in plotData? What does `force.nodes()` return?

Comment: @CoolBlue - how can I check force.node() to the console ?

Comment: It returns the nodes array that's in the force layout. Just set a break point in the tick callback and make a watch for `force.nodes()` (assuming that you called it force) or simply type force.nodes() into the console after the break point is hit. .

Comment: The node also returns the correct count in the array. Thank you for the explanation on how to use a breakpoint. I have a filter in the code that must be responsible. I will post here once I found out why this happens.

Comment: `d3.selectAll(".circle")
      .filter(function(d) {
          var ref;
          return ref = textValue(d), indexOf.call(arraylocal, ref) >= 0;})
      .style("display", "none");`       reduces the array row count to 74 even though the array local is empty

Comment: That filter does nothing to the `force.nodes()` array if that's what you mean? And if `arraylocal` has length 0 then all elements in the document of class circle will be invisible. But we have no idea what else you are doing in your `.tick` callback or in your force layout initialisation. You need to post that if you want help. By the way, you need to tag your comment with my id otherwise I don't get notified ;)

Comment: @Cool Blue - up to the filter the count is ok. The circles that have a match are not being displayed = circle id matches with a string in arraylocal. I have to analyze a little more

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the error in your comma expression: you need parentheses.  
`d3.selectAll(".circle") .filter(function(d) { var ref; return (ref = textValue(d), indexOf.call(arraylocal, ref) >= 0)}) .style("display", "none");`

Comment: @CoolBlue. Thank you for the update. The filter is working now. It does not display duplicates entries from the csv. I am not sure why. With localStorage empty, I do `var key = "";
    arraylocal = [];
    for (key in localStorage) {
      arraylocal.push(key);
    }
    d3.selectAll(".bubble-circle")
      .filter(function(d) {var ref;return (ref = textValue(d), indexOf.call(arraylocal, ref) >= 0);})
      .style("display", "none");` and all items except duplicate entries are being displayed. I will try to find why the duplicates are not being rendered. Code is adapted from Jim's bubble chart

Comment: @CoolBlue  `labelEnter = label.enter()
                      .append("a")
                      .attr("class", "bubble-label")
                      .attr("href", function(d) {return "#" + (encodeURIComponent(idValue(d)));})
                      .call(force.drag)
                      .call(connectEvents);` returns null on the duplicate csv entries.

Comment: @CoolBlue to make this not an overly long discussion I moved to 'd3.js  data binding key function issue duplicate entries from the csv being returned as null' to ask it more specifically as it is neither a slice nor a filter issue. Thank you.